# Z(in) for small signal analysis with BJT for unbypassed emitter and r0 in place

Tags: analysis, bjt, modeling

I have been studying the small signal analysis of BJT with r<sub>e</sub> model with the emitter terminal not bypassed. I am able to derive those Z<sub>i</sub>, Z<sub>o</sub>,A<sub>v</sub>, A<sub>i</sub> long as r<sub>o</sub> is assumed to be infinite. But I am unable to find Z<sub>i</sub> with a finite r<sub>o</sub>. Following is the circuit diagram:

[image]

Below is the equivalent r<sub>e</sub> model:
[image]

I tried with google, but have not been able to find any. Everywhere the solution is done omitting r<sub>o</sub>.Kindly help me with the analysis or provide some helpful link.  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

let, beta=B

From my analysis, V<sub>b</sub>=I<sub>b</sub>[Br<sub>e</sub>+(B+1)R<sub>E</sub>]

So, Z<sub>b</sub>=V<sub>b</sub>/I<sub>b</sub>= [Br<sub>e</sub>+(B+1)R<sub>E</sub>]

Z<sub>i</sub>=R<sub>B</sub>||Zb

But the expression for Z<sub>b</sub> given in the book by Boylestad and Nashelsky is

Z<sub>b</sub>=Br<sub>e</sub>+[{(B+1)+R<sub>C</sub>/r<sub>o</sub>}/{1+(R<sub>C</sub>+R<sub>E</sub>)/r<sub>o</sub>}]R<sub>E</sub>

which I am not able to understand. Please explain it.

Comment: The issue is that your first equation ignores r_o. It assumes the current I_E is (beta+1)I_B, which is only true if you assume r_o is infinite. If you consider r_o, you need to consider the current that goes through it (meaning some of the beta*I_b from the dependent source goes through r_o).

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Let the current through r0 be Ir. Applying KCL,

```
1.  Ie = (B*Ib) + Ib + Ir.
2. Io = Ir + (B*Ib).
```

Applying KVL,

```
(Io*Rc) + (Ir*r0) + (Ie*Re) = 0.
```

From eq 2:

```
Ir = -[(B*Ib*Rc) + Ie*Re]/r0+Rc.

Ie = (1+B)*Ib - [(B*Ib*Rc) + (Ie*Re)]/(r0+Rc).

Ie(1 + (Re/r0+Rc)) = (1+B)Ib - (B*Ib*Rc)/r0+Rc.

Vb = Ib(B*Re) + Ie*Re.  

Vb= Ib(B*Re) + Ib*Re[(B+1) + (Rc/r0)]/[1 + (Rc+Re)/r0]

Zb = B*Re + Re[(b+1) + (Rc/r0)]/[1+(Rc+Re)/r0]
```

Please pardon me I don't know which software to use for formatting. I tried to upload an image, but it failed. I have skipped some of the steps which could be easily arranged.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by converting the `current controlled current source` to `current controlled voltage source` by using `source transformation technique`. So applying ***source-transformation technique***, this circuit will look like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKGVhm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We will obtain two equations, when we apply KVL rule both in input and output side.

**Note:**

Current through resistor \${\beta}r_e\$ is \$ i_b\$;

Current through \$r_O\$  and \$R_c\$ is \$ i_c\$;

Current through resistor \$R_E\$ is \$ i_e\$ = \$i_c\$ + \$i_b\$

**Analysis**

For input side,

\$V_b = i_b.{\beta}r_e + {(i_b+i_c)}R_E\$

=> \$V_b = i_b.({\beta}r_e + R_e) + i_c.R_E\$ --------------->**equation-1**

For output side,

\${i_b}{\beta}{r_o} = {(i_b+i_c)}R_E + {i_c}{R_E} + {i_c}{r_o}\$ --------------->**equation-2**

From equation-2, we can derive an equation for \$i_c\$ in terms of \$i_b\$.

\$i_c = i_b.\cfrac{({B}r_o-R_E)}{(R_E+R_c+r_o)}\$

Substituting it in equation-1 yields

\$V_b = i_b.({\beta}r_e + R_E) + {({i_b}{.\cfrac{({\beta}r_o-R_E)}{(R_E+R_c+r_o)}})}.{Re}\$

So Ib is common in right hand side. Taking it outside as common,

\$V_b = {i_b}.({{\beta}{r_e} + R_E + {\cfrac{(B.ro-Re)}{(Re+Rc+ro)}}.R_E})\$

Taking \$R_E\$ common from the second and third terms in the RHS, then

\$V_b = {i_b}.({\beta}r_e + ({1 + {\cfrac{({\beta}.r_o-R_E)}{(R_E+R_c+r_o)}}).R_E})\$ ---------->**equation-3**

\$V_b = {i_b}.({\beta}r_e + (\cfrac{(R_c+(1 + {\beta})r_o)}{(R_E+R_c+r_o)}.R_E)\$

Dividing numerator and denominator of second term in RHS by \$r_o\$ results

\$V_b = {i_b}.({\beta}r_e + (\cfrac{( (1+{\beta})+{\cfrac{Rc}{ro}})}{( 1+{\cfrac{(R_E+Rc)}{ro}})})\$

**\$=>Z_B=\cfrac{V_b}{i_b} = {\beta}r_e + (\cfrac{( (1+{\beta})+{\cfrac{Rc}{ro}})}{( 1+{\cfrac{(R_E+Rc)}{ro}})}\$**

so circuit input impedance will be \$Z_i=R_b || Z_b\$

Comment: This result cannot be OK. The second term is dimensionless and must not be added to a resistance.

Comment: which is the second term ?? I didnt get

Comment: The second term of the last formula Zb=...

Comment: you are wrong.. in that equation first term  and second term are resistance itself.. second one is not constant. its a pure resisrance term

Comment: Pure resistance? Can you justify this claim? What is the dimension of Rc/ro ?

Comment: resistance. we are dividing a resistance by another resistance. result will be a resistane itself.. a simple example is 2ohm/2ohm. its result is is not 1. its 1ohm. that is unit will be preserved.

Comment: so Rc is resistance. ro also resistane. while divide them, u will get a resistance itself. similarly, the second term's numerator is a resistane, denominator is also a resistance. hence when divide them, we will get a resistance itself

Comment: Quote: "2ohm/2ohm. its result is is not 1. its 1ohm." Who was your teacher? Who told you such nonsense? Blame on him!!!

Comment: first correct you... then try to blame my teacher... i stand for my words.. if u think my answer is wrong, then you can downvote and leave.

Comment: Yes - good idea. By the way - even the equation after your equation (2) is already false. I am not willing to furhter discuss if Ohm/Ohm equals Ohm. Ask one of your friends.

Comment: i am a graduate in electronics and i have no doubt in what i have said.. better u ask to ur friends.

Comment: ...graduate in electronics? Unbelievable!

Comment: @LvW I referred a book yesterday and u r right. pardon me. i am an electronics graduate.. but i work in totally different field. when i realize i forgot this very basic.. i became shocked. i applied the same rule of addition and substraction for division too.. it's my big mistake. sorry for all troubles. in order to review my answer, i need to study signal analysis again ( since electronics is fully out of touch now). but will spend some time and try to correct it. if u can spot the pblm in my analysis, then pls point it out. i will correct it. again sorry for all troubles.. thanks for ur tym

Comment: Thanks for your last message. It is always good if somebody is able to admit his own mistakes. We all are (better: should be) in a process of continuos learning.

Comment: Hello, in the 2nd equation, it is RC, not RE

Answer (score 0):

With this diagram

[image]

\$V_b = i_b~{\beta}~r_e + i_e ~R_E\$

\$ \beta~i_b~ro = i_e~R_E -(-i_c) [r_o+R_C]\$

\$ i_e = i_b+i_c\$

[image]

[image]

It gets
[image]