# Zₒ for small signal analysis with BJT for unbypassed emitter and rₒ in place

Tags: bjt, small-signal

[image]

I try to solve Z<sub>out</sub> for this BJT small-signal model but I find

R<sub>C</sub> || (r<sub>o</sub> + R<sub>E</sub>)

because Z<sub>out</sub> is calculated with I<sub>b</sub> = 0 => βI<sub>b</sub> = 0.

From this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49221/zin-for-small-signal-analysis-with-bjt-for-unbypassed-emitter-and-r0-in-place) too V<sub>in</sub> was calculated.

But the expression for Z<sub>o</sub> given in the book by Boylestad and Nashelsky is:

Z<sub>o</sub> = R<sub>C</sub> || (r<sub>o</sub> + β (r<sub>o</sub> + r<sub>e</sub>) / (1 + β r<sub>e</sub> / R<sub>E</sub>)])

Can you explain how to derive this?

Comment: Put the schematic in your question.

Comment: Just a question for you. What happens to \$Z_o\$ when \$R_\text{E}=0\:\Omega\$ from your last equation? Is it sensible?

Comment: If RE=0 Ω (short circuit) from the last equation Zo = RC || [ ro + β (ro + re) / (1 + infinity)] = Zo = RC || [ ro ] = RC .  It is sensible but considering ib = 0

Comment: Vi = 0 not => ib = 0

Comment: But what do You want to show me by thinking about "RE= 0 Ω" jonk ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution : Vi = 0 not => ib = 0
[image]

Comment: compare it with my solution https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265046/calculation-of-output-impedance-of-ce-emitter-bias-configuration-unbypassed-wi/276764#276764 and here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342859/bjt-common-base-output-resistance-derivation/342989#342989

Answer (score 0):

If you put the equations correctly:

```
point C :   io vo ve ib
point E :      vo ve ib
ib def  :         ve ib
```

3 unknowns : (vo OR io) AND ve AND ib

to get vo = function(io) OR io = function(vo)

[image]